# Querydsl - How to find entities that have String fields containing a specified String?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, querydsl, spring-integration-dsl

I'm using Querydsl with Spring Data JPA. I have the following entities (plus the usual getters, setters, & persistence annotations)

```
class Car {
 int id;
 String color; 
 Model model;
 Make make;
}

class Model {
  int id;
  String name;
}

class Make {
  int id;
  String name;
}
```

I want to find all `Car` entities with color + model.mame + "." + make.name matching a given search String. For example, a blue Toyota Camry would have its String be "blueCamry.Toyota" and it would match the following search Strings (case insensitive):

```
Toyota
camry
blue
eca
y.to
ecamry.T
```

How can this be done using Querydsl with Sring Data JPA?